# Inheritance issues with SQL Server CE and Mango

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to implement SQL Server CE code in Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango). I have two classes, one base class and one inherited - both declared as [Table] with [Column]:s

Can you not have inheritance in SQL Server CE for Mango??

I don't want to change all my Entity classes to not have inheritance....

Might someone know the answer to this?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're doing and what happens.

Comment: Can't do much to help here without some kind of error or indication of what makes you think this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have inheritance in SQLCE for Mango if you follow the LINQ to SQL Inheritance Mapping pattern.

I've blogged about the [Column] inheritance issue [here](http://blog.arsanth.com/index.php/2011/05/30/windows-phone-sql-ce-column-inheritance/) and [here](http://blog.arsanth.com/index.php/2011/05/30/column-inheritance-may-not-be-what-i-thought-it-was/). The LINQ to SQL Inheritance Mapping docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a base class for the class decorated with [Table], but not have two classes both with the [Table] attribute

Comment: I have an [Table] class with som [column] properties...then one of the properties is another class that also is declared with [Table]. This is a must for me or else I have to change many of my EntityClasses. Maybee I need to stick with Sterling instead where I can have this with no problem.